# execute windows powershell script using pom.xml

Tags: maven, powershell, maven-3, pom.xml

I want to execute windows powershell script with Maven. Here is what I tried:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>some-execution</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>D:\Projects\test.ps1</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But it is just opening the powershell script while executing the pom

```
mvn exec:exec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't got any other option so write below line in batch file

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command D:\Projects\Test.ps1
```

and use the exec plugin to call the batch file, which will execute the powershell script.

Like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>some-execution</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>D:\Projects\test1.bat</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: So you figured out how to run a ps1 file properly. Why don't you put that complete command line you have in your batch file to the executable tag?

Comment: it's already there, the first line PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "PathTo ps1 file"

Comment: No. I meant to place the complete cmdline instead of the bat file `<executable>D:\Projects\test1.bat</executable>`

Comment: And BTW. the proper parameter to run a file with Powershell would be `-File`, not `-Command`

Comment: That is a good idea. Then there is no need of keeping the bat also.